# c++ sizeof - need help understanding

Tags: c++, sizeof

I am having trouble understanding a line of code. I see that an array is initialized as follows:

```
static const uint SmartBatteryWattHoursTable[1 << 4] = {
  0,  14,  27,  41,  54,  68,  86, 104,
120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330};
```

However I can't tell what the following code means:

```
int x  = sizeof(SmartBatteryWattHoursTable) / sizeof(*SmartBatteryWattHoursTable));
```

I understand that the numerator will evaluate to 16 * 4 = 64. But what does the denominator evaluate to?

Comment: Is this code trying to be difficult on purpose? `1 << 4` is an obtuse way to express 16. I think the intention of the second part is to de-reference a decayed array pointer to get the size of a single element, or `sizeof(uint)`.

Comment: Tip: In C++ try and use `std::vector` because then the length is `len()`. No guessing.

Comment: you should ask your question with tag C, you will get more friendly answers. Good luck rookie!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c

Comment: I guess you never thought of doing `std::cout << sizeof(*SmartBatteryWattHoursTable);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is declaring an array of 16 (`1 << 4`) `uint` values.

The statement `sizeof(SmartBatteryWattHoursTable)` returns the byte size of the entire array, thus `sizeof(uint) * 16 = 64` (assuming a 4-byte `uint`).

An array [*decays*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay) into a pointer to the 1st element, thus `*SmartBatteryWattHoursTable` is the same as `*(&SmartBatteryWattHoursTable[0])`.  So the statement `sizeof(*SmartBatteryWattHoursTable)` returns the byte size of the 1st element of the array, ie of a single `uint`, thus `4`.

Thus, `x` is set to `64 / 4 = 16`, ie the number of elements in the array.

This is a very common way to get the element size of a fixed array, prior to the addition of [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) to the standard C++ library in C++17 (and `std::ssize()` in C++20).

Comment: Very well explained. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7):

> But what does the denominator evaluate to?

`sizeof(*SmartBatteryWattHoursTable)` evaluates to the size of the type of the expression `*SmartBatteryWattHoursTable`. The type of that expression is the same as the element of the array, which is `uint`.

In other words, `sizeof(SmartBatteryWattHoursTable) / sizeof(*SmartBatteryWattHoursTable))` is a way to calculate the size of the array in number of elements (as opposed to the size in number of bytes that the numerator is).

A simpler way to write this is `std::size(SmartBatteryWattHoursTable)`.

Comment: you mean, `*SmartBatteryWattHoursTable == SmartBatteryWattHoursTable[0]`? i.e. `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @Lucas Yup. More on the subject: [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) One big take away is arrays are NOT pointers, but can be viewed as pointers.

Comment: @MichaelMcKinney There are the (brand-new) clapping hands under the vote arrows (introduced in the hope to get rid of the "Thank you" comments). ;-) Btw. Please, don't forget to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) which helped you most.